# str to float conversion error in python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to get `abs` of `float`, which is initially stored in `str` as:

```
for q in range(0, len(moms), 1):
    print("mom types", type(moms[q]))
    out.write(abs(float(moms[q]))+" ")
out.write("\n")
```

which gives error:

```
mom types <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s2gen.py", line 192, in <module>
    out.write(abs(float(moms[q]))+" ")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

I am not regular in python, but it seems, the string to float is correct, as from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int). Not sure, what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a `float` value and a `str` value; you have to convert the result of the `abs` function back to a `str` explicitly before adding a space to it.

```
out.write(str(abs(float(moms[q]))) + " ")
```